# Magento add tags and add to wishlist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

If I am not login and click add tags or add to wishlist buttons on a product page, the website will be redirected to homepage and ask me to login.

flow:
(product page) -> (homepage and popup login light box)->(stay homepage)

but what i hope to display like below(1 or 2):

1. (product page) -> (stay product page and popup login light box)->(stay product page)
2. (product page) -> (homepage and popup login light box)->(back to product page)

Thanks for all of you.

---

[update on 2014/1/17]

as you can see in this page:http://en.tartoo.com.tw/illustrators/bears.html

if you click "+add to wishlist", the page will redirect to homepage and ask you log in.

After you login in, the page will stay on the homepage.

However, the customer cannot find the original product which he wants to add to his wishlist....

Could any one give some help on this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to customized magento existign module

Comment: Hello after success login check $this->_redirect(); function